# awk delete between two patterns reading from input file in one shot

Tags: awk

Hello  and thanks in advance for your help.

Trying to make a script with awk, but fails and i wonder if this is posible to do. Read from input file and delete lines between two patterns, for example.

File1 contains:

```
user2
```

and File2 contains the lines:

```
ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678

ID: user2
Telpephone: 1324-6598

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543
```

The desired output is like:

```
ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543
```

I can do it in a loop, but with big files is taking too long, it is posible to do in a single shot with awk?

Regards.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what is it that you are trying to do. Example given would  suggest dropping lines from File2 matching content/patter from File1. But title suggest dropping between matches? In your example, what would happen if there was another line containing user2? Would you drop all line between them? And if there were two, three, four... more such line? Exclude all between outermost matches? Or interleaved?

Comment: Drop between matches thats correct, for example matching between user2 and the first space. If find 1, 2, 3, deletes all of them and drop lines between them.                     for example with command awk '/user2/,/^$/{next}{print}' file2, it is posible to delete all lines between user2 and white space. The issue or what i'm trying to do is, with huge multiple input string, for example for 10,000 user input and in a file2 o 1GB size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat skip
user2
$ cat file
ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678

ID: user2
Telpephone: 1324-6598

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543
```

With `awk` in paragraph mode:

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"}
      FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) skip[$i]; next}
      $2 in skip {next}
      1' skip file
ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543
```

---

With the update, now supports multiple skip words:

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"}
      FNR==NR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) skip[$i]; next}
      $2 in skip {next}
      1' <(echo "user2 user3") file
ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678
```

Comment: Is there a posible way to skip more than a single match?                                                   

$ cat skip

user1
user2

$ cat file

ID: user1
Telpephone: 1234-5678

ID: user2
Telpephone: 1324-6598

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543

Output:

ID: user3
Telpephone: 9087-6543

Comment: Yes. Fixed. Just put the matches in either space delimited or on individual lines.

Comment: Best regards dawg, it works perfectly just as you mentioned.